# Using IntelliJ for a Scala Project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am missing something simple here.

- Scala downloaded
- Scala home set
- IntelliJ plugin downloaded

When new module is added, scala is chosen:

[image]

When new class is created, however, when trying to run it, i get

[image]

Looking as module properties, i see

[image]

What am i missing please?

Comment: You might try selecting "Application" while adding a new configuration, instead of "Scala Script".  (BTW, if you can type "scala" at the console prompt and it starts your environment is probably OK.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. The file you're working with must be a Scala *class*.
2. You should have an `object` declared somewhere (preferably outside of the class).

   ```
   object runnableObject {
       def main(args: Array[String]) {
           println("Hello world!")
       }
   }
   ```

You can then use this object to run your Scala code in IntelliJ.

Comment: I am getting "Cannot resolve symbol Array". It looks almost as if my JVM is not set up right

Comment: Definitely.  Make sure your JVM is pointing to the proper location, or you'll get errors like that all day.

Comment: Where in IDEA i can confirm that things are well? What do you have listed under "Libraries"?

Comment: @CrazyCoder My SDK is set up and points to 1.7. Note i have no issues with Java projects

Comment: Of notable importance would be the scala-2.9.2/lib JAR files.

Comment: @Makoto Indeed. I explicitly pointed to libs and all went well. Thank you sir